# Is every compact, homogeneous, totally disconnected space a power of a finite discrete space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, homogeneous-spaces

In a comment of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16829), t.b. suggests that every compact, homogeneous, totally disconnected, second countable space is either a finite discrete space or the Cantor set; equivalently, it must be a countable power of a finite discrete space. How can this be proven?

Furthermore, $2^\kappa$ is compact, homogeneous, and totally disconnected. Is every compact, homogeneous and totally disconnected space (not necessarily second countable) a power of a finite discrete space?

Comment: If $X$ is compact, homogeneous, totally disconnected, second countable but not discrete, then $X$ has no isolated points, so it is a Cantor set by [Brouwer's characterization theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space#Characterization)

Comment: It's not clear to me that a compact, homogeneous, totally disconnected space is Hausdorff. Might be that Hausdorff must be added as a prerequisite, even in case of second countable?

Comment: totally disconnected gets you T1, so proving regular gets you Hausdorff.

Comment: why is it regular?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "would get you". I have not been successful in verifying this.

Comment: None of the compact, non Hausdorff, disconnected spaces in pi-Base are homogeneous, so that'd be a nice counterexample to have as well: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=~T_2%2B~Connected%2BCompact

Comment: I just added a much simpler counterexample to the second question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the second question is "no", even in the realm of Hausdorff spaces:

Let $X$ be the Double arrow space. It is well-known that $X$ is compact, Hausdorff, zero-dimensional, first countable, but not metrizable.
By Theorem 2 in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-08/S0002-9939-97-03998-1/S0002-9939-97-03998-1.pdf) of Alan Dow and Elliot Pearl, $X^\omega$ is homogeneous. Of course, $X^\omega$ is compact, Hausdorff, zero-dimensional (hence totally disconnected) and first countable. Assume $X^\omega$ is homeomorphic to $D^\kappa$ for a discrete, finite space $D$ and a cardinal $\kappa$. By first countability, $\kappa = \omega$, hence $X^\omega$ is metrizable, hence $X$ is metrizable. Contradiction.

**Update** 
I should have thought a little bit more carefully about this before, since there is a **much** simpler counterexample, which also avoids this very complicated theorem of Dow and Pearl:

The endpoints of the Double arrow space are isolated, hence $Z := X \setminus \{\text{min } X, \text{max } X \}$ is also compact. It is well-known (and not too difficult to see) that $Z$ is homogeneous. Of course, it is also zero-dimensional, Hausdorff, first countable. Hence it is not homeomorphic to $D^\kappa$ for a discrete, finite space $D$.

Anyway, for reference, and since it has already been accepted, I will keep the first example.